# I want to add double quotes to each column name without changing the datatype of their values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a data frame with a lot of columns (around 600). I want specific columns from the 600 columns. I specify these columns in a

list `[t01 .., t08, t09, t10, t11, t12, t13 ..... t600]`.

Right now I am just copying this from the csv file.

I want the list to be like this:

`['t10', 't11', 't12', 't13' ..... 't400']`.

In order to do this, I would have to manually put double quotes around each column name.

Is there a way to directly put double quotes around columns that start from `t10` and end at `t400`? The columns are side by side and they make a range (t10-t401) .

I would store this in

`features = df[col_names]` and use it in something like :

```
scaler.fit_transform(features.values)
```

Comment: You say you `specify these columns in a list [t01 .., t08...`. Not sure what that means. Are you looking for a way to turn a string like `"[t01, t02, t03, t04, t05, t06,...]"` into a list of strings like `['t01', 't02', 't03', 't04',...]`? If so you can strip the `[]` off and split: `some_string.strip('[]').split(', ')`

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying. So I copy the column names from a csv file. When I do that, I don't get the double quote around the names. But inorder to perform scaler.fit_transform(df[col_names.values), the column names need double quotes around them, to extract the values from each column. So I am looking for a way to convert [t01, t02, t03, t04, t05, t06,...] to ['t01', 't02', 't03', 't04',...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension with format of strings:

```
['t{0}'.format(x) for x in range(10,401)]

#output:
['t10', 't11', 't12', 't13', 't14', 't15', 't16', 't17', 't18', 't19', 't20', 't21', 't22', 't23', 't24', 't25', 't26', 't27', 't28', 't29', 't30', 't31', 't32', 't33', 't34', 't35', 't36', 't37', 't38', 't39', 't40', 't41', 't42', 't43', 't44', 't45', 't46', 't47', 't48', 't49', 't50', 't51', 't52', 't53', 't54', 't55', 't56', 't57', 't58', 't59', 't60', 't61', 't62', 't63', 't64', 't65', 't66', 't67', 't68', 't69', 't70', 't71', 't72', 't73', 't74', 't75', 't76', 't77', 't78', 't79', 't80', 't81', 't82', 't83', 't84', 't85', 't86', 't87', 't88', 't89', 't90', 't91', 't92', 't93', 't94', 't95', 't96', 't97', 't98', 't99', 't100', 't101', 't102', 't103', 't104', 't105', 't106', 't107', 't108', 't109', 't110', 't111', 't112', 't113', 't114', 't115', 't116', 't117', 't118', 't119', 't120', 't121', 't122', 't123', 't124', 't125', 't126', 't127', 't128', 't129', 't130', 't131', 't132', 't133', 't134', 't135', 't136', 't137', 't138', 't139', 't140', 't141', 't142', 't143', 't144', 't145', 't146', 't147', 't148', 't149', 't150', 't151', 't152', 't153', 't154', 't155', 't156', 't157', 't158', 't159', 't160', 't161', 't162', 't163', 't164', 't165', 't166', 't167', 't168', 't169', 't170', 't171', 't172', 't173', 't174', 't175', 't176', 't177', 't178', 't179', 't180', 't181', 't182', 't183', 't184', 't185', 't186', 't187', 't188', 't189', 't190', 't191', 't192', 't193', 't194', 't195', 't196', 't197', 't198', 't199', 't200', 't201', 't202', 't203', 't204', 't205', 't206', 't207', 't208', 't209', 't210', 't211', 't212', 't213', 't214', 't215', 't216', 't217', 't218', 't219', 't220', 't221', 't222', 't223', 't224', 't225', 't226', 't227', 't228', 't229', 't230', 't231', 't232', 't233', 't234', 't235', 't236', 't237', 't238', 't239', 't240', 't241', 't242', 't243', 't244', 't245', 't246', 't247', 't248', 't249', 't250', 't251', 't252', 't253', 't254', 't255', 't256', 't257', 't258', 't259', 't260', 't261', 't262', 't263', 't264', 't265', 't266', 't267', 't268', 't269', 't270', 't271', 't272', 't273', 't274', 't275', 't276', 't277', 't278', 't279', 't280', 't281', 't282', 't283', 't284', 't285', 't286', 't287', 't288', 't289', 't290', 't291', 't292', 't293', 't294', 't295', 't296', 't297', 't298', 't299', 't300', 't301', 't302', 't303', 't304', 't305', 't306', 't307', 't308', 't309', 't310', 't311', 't312', 't313', 't314', 't315', 't316', 't317', 't318', 't319', 't320', 't321', 't322', 't323', 't324', 't325', 't326', 't327', 't328', 't329', 't330', 't331', 't332', 't333', 't334', 't335', 't336', 't337', 't338', 't339', 't340', 't341', 't342', 't343', 't344', 't345', 't346', 't347', 't348', 't349', 't350', 't351', 't352', 't353', 't354', 't355', 't356', 't357', 't358', 't359', 't360', 't361', 't362', 't363', 't364', 't365', 't366', 't367', 't368', 't369', 't370', 't371', 't372', 't373', 't374', 't375', 't376', 't377', 't378', 't379', 't380', 't381', 't382', 't383', 't384', 't385', 't386', 't387', 't388', 't389', 't390', 't391', 't392', 't393', 't394', 't395', 't396', 't397', 't398', 't399', 't400']
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please accept my answer by clicking tick mark near the vote button.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do that. I apologize.

Comment: You do not need any reputation to do this. Just click the 'tick mark. It is below the vote button.